# I need to find Roots of the below equation. Also I need plots on a single graph

Tags: plotting

Tan[x] = (x*((3.13*(sqrt (162.30 - x^2))) + (5.23*(sqrt (334.35 - 
            x^2))))/(2.10*x^2 - (9.81*((sqrt (162.30 - x^2))*(sqrt (334.35 - x^2))))))

This is my equation. I have tried several option but I am getting only Tan[x] part. RHS part I am not getting.

Comment: All Mathematica functions start with a capital letter. Also, see [`Four Kinds of Bracketing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

Answer (score 4):

To help `NSolve`, constrain the domain of x to solve on.

```
rhs  = (x*((3.13*(Sqrt [162.30 - x^2])) 
         + (5.23*(Sqrt [334.35 - x^2])))/
           (2.10*x^2 - (9.81*((Sqrt [162.30 - x^2])*(Sqrt [334.35 - x^2])))));

eq   = Tan[x] == rhs;
pts  = x /. NSolve[eq && 0 <= x <= 4 Pi, x]
pts  = {#, Tan[#]} & /@ pts
```

gives

```
{{0.,0.},{2.96219,-0.181358},{5.90033,-0.402731},{8.77135,-0.765628}, {11.4446,-2.07536}}
```

Now plot it

```
range = {Range[0, 4 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic};
Plot[{rhs, Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi},
 Ticks -> range,
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[pts]},
 GridLines -> range, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You So much.